# Error bars from plot()

Tags: r, plot

I'm using R's generic function `plot()` to plot count data as a function of a nominal variable, where `count` is a vector of integers and `colour` is a variable containing two categories:

```
varb = c('red','red','red','red','blue','blue','blue','blue')
count = c(3,1,0,2,2,0,6,2)

df = data.frame(varb,count)
plot(count ~ varb, data=df)
```

[image]

My question is: what do the error bars represent? Are they 95% confidence intervals? Standard deviations? Standard error?

Thanks!

Comment: From bottom to top: minimum value, 25% of observations, 50% of observations 75% of observations and maximum value.

Comment: aaaaah - that makes much more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explain in more detail I've used your code and added labels to plot for the explanation

```
# Plot your data
plot(count ~ varb, data=df)
# Add text to plot
text(x= 1, y= 6.1, labels= "Largest value")
text(x= 1, y= -0.1, labels= "Smalest value")
text(x= 1, y=2.1, labels= "Median")
text(x= 1, y=4.1, labels= "Upper quartile (75%)")
text(x= 1, y= 1.1, labels= "Lower quartile (25%")
```

And the image to explain (note that I've labeled only first plot)

[image]

With boxplot, we visualize the distribution of data based on the following summary: minimum (i.e., smallest value), first quartile (i.e., lower quartile), median, third quartile (i.e., upper quartile), and maximum (i.e., largest value). Note that the distance from the first quartile to the third quartile presents the interquartile range or IQR (IQR is related to the variability of your sample data).

Comment: thanks for this. I'm assuming that the min and max values are restricted to 1 SD of the mean? The reason I ask is because other plots show outliers which exceed the 'maximum' value shown by the uppermost bar

Comment: Not exactly. The max will be the end of the upper whisker, (i.e., the max value in your data) and the min will be the end of the lower whisker (i.e., the min value in your data), unless either the max or min is considered an outlier. An outlier is an observation that is 1.5 * IQR distant from the rest of the data. When reviewing a boxplot, an outlier is defined as a data point that is located outside of the boxplot (e.g. outside 1.5 * IQR above the upper quartile and 1.5 * IQR below the lower quartile